# need help to display letter pressed in a div with javascript

Tags: javascript

here's what i got so far, i get "undefined" in the div instead of the actual letter pressed.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    document.onkeydown = checkKeycode;

    function checkKeycode(e) 
    {
        var keycode;
        if (window.event) 
        {
            keycode = window.event.keyCode;
        }
        else if (e) keycode = e.which;

        var character = String.fromCharCode(keycode);
        var letterDiv = document.getElementById("letter1");
        letterDiv.innerHTML =character.innerHTML;
</script>
```

Comment: Guessing a typo but you are missing a closing }

Comment: Have a look at the console. I bet you get an error.

Answer (score 1):

Here's [JSFiddle Demo:](http://jsfiddle.net/kjy112/cXyg9/)

Set the letterDiv's innerHtml to that of `var character` not `character.innerHTML`. `var character` is a string not an Element.

```
document.onkeydown = checkKeycode;

    function checkKeycode(e) {
        var keycode;
        if (window.event) {
            keycode = window.event.keyCode;
        }
        else if (e) keycode = e.which;

        var character = String.fromCharCode(keycode);
        var letterDiv = document.getElementById("letter1");
        letterDiv.innerHTML = character;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `innerHTML` from `character` like so:

```
letterDiv.innerHTML = character;
```

Also, in your example, it appears that you are missing the end bracket `}` for your function.  I suspect this problem does not exist in your actual project.